# KeywordTokenizerFactory with LowerCaseFilterFactory

Tags: solr, indexing

I wanted to use a NGramFilterFactory for my index and saw following example and tryed it out:

```
<fieldType name="NGramText" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
 <analyzer type="index">
   <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>  
   <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/> 
   <filter class="solr.NGramFilterFactory" minGramSize="2" maxGramSize="25" />

 </analyzer>
 <analyzer type="query">
 <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
 <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
 </analyzer>
</fieldType>


<field name="mark" type="NGramText" indexed="true" stored="true" omitNorms="true" omitTermFreqAndPositions="true"/>
```

The example is using KeywordTokenizerFactory. What is the purpose of using this? From what i understand it really do not do anythig, " the entire
input string is preserved as a single token " it says on the net.

Is there a good reason to use KeywordTokenizerFactory to make Ngrams or could i change it for WhitespaceTokenizerFactory with out slowing down the searches?

And also with this example LowerCaseFilterFactory is not making the fields lowercase could that has something to do with the conjunction with KeywordTokenizerFactory?

Comment: KeywordTokenizerFactory, as you said preserves the whole String as a single token.. I guess there is no good reason to use it to generate ngrams.. you can use KeywordTokenizerFactory whenever you want to perform operation on entire string.. Eg: Faceting.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why LowerCaseFilterFactory dosent work with this setup?

Comment: You can check what the index time analyzer is doing by using the analysis tool located at this URL; `http://HOST:PORT/solr/#/CORE/analysis`

Comment: When using this tool it seams like the letters is converted to lower case, but when indexing it does not for some reason.